# Deleting a remote branch works, local pruning does not. why?

Tags: git, git-remote

On my setup, this seems to work to delete a remote branch:

```
git push origin :foo
```

Because when I do it the first time, it's successful, but the second time, it fails because it says the remote branch is not there (as expected). So far so good.

This does not work:

```
git remote prune origin
```

It returns with no output, and all my local tracking branches for the deleted remotes are still there.

Answer (score 2):

By "local tracking branches", do you mean branches *you* created to track remote branches? `git remote prune` won't delete those. It'll only delete the remote branches (i.e., it'll delete `origin/foo`, but not `my-local-foo` that tracked `origin/foo`).

You can confirm that `origin/foo` was deleted by checking the output of

```
$ git branch -r
```

Comment: ah whoops, got my terminology wrong. yeah, i meant remote branches. `git branch -r` still shows **origin/foo**